# Why is Reader ID in AMP Access given that Client ID exists?

Tags: amp-html

My understanding is that Reader ID is a well-known instance of a Client ID. But from what I can tell, any Client ID can be injected into an amp:access URL, so I don't totally follow why Reader ID needs to exist at all. The documentation implies something about security but doesn't go into details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's just an instance of Client ID. It's just have a standardized scope for two main reasons:

1. It's explicitly allowed to be used without consent since access is a fundamental part of content serving.
2. It's simplifies referencing of it for analytics.